# PHP dados do cliente listar em JSON

Tags: php, json

Boa tarde galera,

bom eu tenho um CRUD em PHP e preciso fazer com que os clientes cadastrados sejam mostrados em outra URL em JSON

Mas comi sou meio fraco em PHP eu não tenho idea de como fazer isso com dados vindos de uma consulta no BD, alguem tem conhecimento de como fazer?

Comment: Coloca o código em questão, para ver se pode-se fazer qualquer coisa.

Answer (score 1):

Assumindo que os dados que você trouxe do BD estejam em um array ou objeto chamado `$data` basta usar a função `json_encode`, o código ficaria algo assim:

```
// código para obter os dados do BD
echo json_encode($data);
```

Mais detalhes sobre a função json_encode aqui: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Putz, e eu achando que era algo bem mais complicado. Valeu!!!